# Spring data mongodb, spring data rest override repository interface method whith @query and @update without creating search endpoint

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest

I want to override the behavior of the deleteById method in a mongorepository interface with @query and @update spring data mongodb repository annotations but when i do so it creates a new endpoint GET /entityname/search/deleteById; i dont want this endpoint.
note: When you make a request to that endpoint it responds with a 404 but handles the request and executes the update correctly.
If i dont expose the endpoint with @RestResource(exported = false) the endpoint is correctly hidden but the DELETE /entityname/{id} stops working
This is for a soft-delete logic
I dont want a controller

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a way to hide the newly created endpoint, I would suggest to make a custom endpoint manually for the delete operation. You may need to create a separate repository by extending JpaRepository directly. This may not be an optimal solution, but one that will definitely work.

Comment: I cannot hide the new search endpoint because that also breaks the DELETE /entityname/{id} one. That is the one I need to keep, also, Im using mongorepository, not jpa

Comment: My idea is to hide the one being autocreated and replace it with a custom one to handle the delete operation. This should work since it's just another endpoint. I have not worked with MongoRepository so I can't be of further help.